# Fare rules information in the response of search

Tags: amadeus

I could not find the fare rule information in the response of flight search API and flight offer price API (self-service).

According to the swagger (provided in the document), such information should be in `offer.fareRules`. Do you have any idea to fetch this information? Because I'd like to fetch the information such as refund, exchange etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Flight Offers Price API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-price/api-reference) you need to use the query parameter `include` with the value `detailed-fare-rules`

[image]

For example:

> https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing?include=detailed-fare-rules

You will get the `detailed-fare-rules` as part of the response into `included`:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I make a try with the `detailed-fare-rules` parameter, it works well for offer price API, but not for search flight API. Do you know how we can get such information from search flight API?

Comment: At search time the information is not always available, I will strongly recommend to use it at price time